# bluetooth bulb change mode android

Tags: java

Im developing a bluetooth application which turn on or off Bulb, I already connects the bluetooth bulb, but I cant change the mode from on to off and reverse.

this is my code:
inlude what is one //

```
public void turnOnAll(View view) {
  //  Map<String, BLEService.BLEDeviceContext> devices = bleService.getUsedDevices();
     for (BLEService.BLEDeviceContext d : devices.values()) {
          d.changeStatus(true);
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  //  findViewById(R.id.btn_turn_off_all).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This is change status method:

```
 public void changeStatus(boolean on) {
        if (characteristicLight == null) {
            return;
        }

        lightOn = on;
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, on ? "准备亮灯" : "准备灭灯");
        byte[] value = new byte[] { red, green, blue, (byte) 0x00, on ? (byte) 0x64 : (byte) 0x00 };
        readWriteWorker.submit(new Task(value, characteristicLight, gatt));
    }
```

I think the problem is that the "submit" method does not send the key right, 
this is my UUID:

```
private static final UUID SERVICE_LIGHT_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private static final UUID CHARACTERISTIC_LIGHT_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: Generally you should approach a problem like this by simplification and comparison to example code that does work, by examining what is actually sent, or by using a debugger on the peripheral end to see what is received.  Can you query the value of this characteristic from the peripheral?  Can you use a generic BLE characteristic browser/setter app to change the light?

Comment: I know what the characteristic with the debuger but I don`t know if it the right value ..

Comment: As you are the one with the unspecified hardware, how could anyone here help you know if it is correct?